# woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation how error in Ajax

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a function that checked stock in 3 party Software.(it's for double check).
I am working with add to cart by Ajax.
I am trying to show an error to user if there is no stock.
Thanks

```php
function so_validate_add_cart_item($passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = '', $variations = '') {

    global $product;

    $variation_o = new WC_Product_Variation($_POST['variation_id']);
    $variations_stock = $variation_o->get_stock_quantity();
    $varSku = get_post_meta($_POST['variation_id'], '_wp_sku', true);
    $get_parent_id = $variation_o->get_parent_id();

    $livequantity = get_update_quantity($varSku, $get_parent_id, $_POST['variation_id']);

    if ($livequantity <= 0) {

        $passed = false;
        $message = __("No stock", "woocommerce");
        echo '<div class="woocommerce-info hidden" style="display:none;">' . $message . '</div>';

    }
    return $passed;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'so_validate_add_cart_item', 10, 5);
```

I the error show if Ajax is disabled.
How can show the error with Ajax?